# How to use pointer on structure in functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

I try to learn how to work with structures in C. I must write a structure that will have the names of students. After that, I create an array of this structure and sort it by the names of students. For this, I wrote a function:

```
void sort_name(struct stuedet *arr, long start, long end)
{
long head = start, tail = end;
long midl = (start + end)/2;

while (1)
{
    while(strcmp(arr[head].name, arr[midl].name) > 0)
    {
        head++;
    }
    while (strcmp(arr[tail].name, arr[midl].name) < 0)
    {
        tail--;
    }
    if (head >= tail)
    {
        break;
    }
    swap(arr, head, tail);
}

sort_name(arr, start, midl);
sort_name(arr, midl, end);
}
```

The first argument is a pointer to that array which I mentioned.
However, there are errors like "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" when I write "arr[head].neme".
Here is my structure:

```
struct student
{
char last_name[40];
char name[40];
char birth_day[10];

short unsigned grades[6];
};
```

I use GCC compiler

Comment: What happens if all names are already sorted? Hint: you access outside of the bounds of the array. You need an extra check: `if (head > tail) break; else head++;`, same for `tail`

Comment: You didn't declared struct at the point where function code is defined. As you wrote "struct student", that makes it a forward declaration, but to use its field you need full declaration.